# How get text right floating and right as a center?

Tags: word-wrap, floating

How get text right floating and right as a center?

```
 $text = "The epic finale that will live foreve";
 $newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
 echo $newtext;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing what is the question:

```
$text = "The epic finale that will live foreve";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 20, "<br />\n");
echo '<div style="float: right; width:50%; text-align: center;">'.$newtext.'</div>';
```

Comment: any idea why i getting text glitch when i wrote word where is in " or ' character so it giving me glitched text original "It's not the plan, it's the execution" glitched text "It\'s not the plan, it\'s the execution"